# Convert Key/Value pairs to json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a string that looks like this:

```
TOKEN="XXX" JOBID="2435" TYPE="ERROR" MSG="<SOME_THING> [name="address"] couldn't be found"
```

What I need to do is convert the key=value pairs to an object or json within nodejs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  String.split(' ') could be a good starting point.

Comment: I have thought about String.split(' '), but for the MSG key, it can have spaces in that value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could split by string delimiters, and extract the key from the "outside" part:

```js
const input='TOKEN="XXX" JOBID="2435" TYPE="ERROR"';
const result={};
     
input.split('"').forEach(function(value, i, arr){
  if(i % 2 === 0) return;
  const key=arr[i-1].trim().replace("=","");
  result[key]=value;
});

console.log(result);
```

A proper Parser would however rather look something like this:

```js
const input='TOKEN="XXX" JOBID="2435" TYPE="ERROR"';
const result = {};

let position = 0;

while(position < input.length) {
  let startKey = position;
  while(input[startKey] === " ") startKey++;
  
  const endKey = input.indexOf(`="`, startKey + 1);
  if(endKey === -1)
    throw new Error("Key without value");
    
  const endValue = input.indexOf(`"`, endKey + 2);
  if(endValue === -1)
    throw new Error("Unterminated Value");
  
  const key   = input.slice(startKey, endKey);
  const value = input.slice(endKey + 2, endValue);
  result[key] = value;
  
  console.log("key", key, "value", value);
  
  position = endValue + 1;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Does't seem to work correctly when including: MSG="<SOME_THING> [name="address"] couldn't be found"

Comment: @james because thats invalid data. Must be name='address'

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: This is so good. I had a scenario of getting a file where if line contains key=value, convert those into a json. I used your strategy & modified according to need. Thank you

Comment: @SatishPatro have a look at the edit, my original version from 2017 wasn't quite good ...

Comment: Nice. Still for me first approach seems nice & simple, I think only more suitable is to split based on space "\s+", then doing, in 2nd one you are iterating but I think below one may take some more time. Not so sure. Extra thing I did in my code is after splitting, I am splitting again by '=" and if length 2, both key, value exist then proceeding, else return

Comment: var fr=new FileReader();
    fr.onload=function(){
     document.getElementById('original')
       .textContent=fr.result;
     var result={};
      fr.result.split('\r\n').forEach(function(value,i,arr){
       let myArr4 = value.split('=');
       if(myArr4.length!==2) return;
       result[myArr4[0].trim()]=myArr4[1].trim();
     });            
     document.getElementById('formatted').textContent=JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2);

Comment: Scenario is there is one property file containing key=value file & some lines are empty or commented lines